# VBA/Powershell Push Parameters and return result

Tags: vba, powershell

Im trying to improve my VBA/Powershell process to handle some new features and im stuck to return values of my powershell.

The purpose of the function is to extract the users from the AD groups which will have been requested previously according to the requester's application (several AD groups possible).

For the moment it works well in test but it saves the result in a text file that I read later by Excel / VBA

VBA Code

```
Sub TestPS()
    
inputAD = "FR-DATACENTER-FDS-ALIZ-13039-Exp"  
cmd = "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -File ""C:\Users\lilian.roche\OneDrive - TRANSDEV\Métiers\Developpement\FDS\Prepaie\TestText.ps1"" -inputAD """ & inputAD & """"
Shell cmd, vbNormalFocus

End Sub
```

Powershell Code

```
param([string]$inputAD)

Import-Module activedirectory

echo $inputAD

$Test = Get-ADGroupMember $inputAD | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

Clear-Host
$MyLine = [string]
$NomFichierACreer = [string]

$varCheminRepertoireScript = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)
$NomFichierACreer = "MonFichier.txt"

$EmplacementFichier = $varCheminRepertoireScript
$EmplacementFichier = "$EmplacementFichier\$NomFichierACreer"
echo $EmplacementFichier

#Création du fichier vierge
$MonFichier = New-Item -type file $EmplacementFichier -Force

$MyLine = $test
echo $MyLine
add-content $MonFichier $inputAD
add-content $MonFichier $MyLine
```

Comment: `For the moment it works well in test but it saves the result in a text file that I read later by Excel / VBA` What exactly is your question?

Comment: Hello,
I need to return the value $MyLine into my Excel to use it after. At the moment I am using the txt file calling it from Excel which adds additional processing

Comment: Consider outputting **objects** and writing that to a structured CSV file. Excel is very capable of importing CSV files after all.